# How to get a model using entity framworks to be reference by a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvvm

I am having a problem referencing a table that is using Entity Frameworks in a View Model.

This is the Model, I'm not really sure why the class is being called a ViewModel but I didn't name it.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} 
     characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation 
     password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

I have a very simple View Model Referencing this model, I think:

```
public class UserCreateNewViewModel
{ 
     public RegisterViewModel Register = new RegisterViewModel(); 
}
```

In my Controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UserCreateNew(RegisterViewModel model)
{

 var m = new UserCreateNewViewModel(); 

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    string registerToken =

   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, 
   model.Password, new { Email = model.Email }, true);
   SimpleSecurity.WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(registerToken);

    string confirmationToken =


    WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(model.UserName);

    dynamic email = new Email("ChngPasswordEmail");
    email.To = model.Email;
    email.UserName = model.UserName;
    email.baseUrl = GetBaseUrl();
    email.ConfirmationToken = confirmationToken;
    email.Send();


  }
  return RedirectToAction("UserList");
}
```

I think its weird that I am trying to pass in RegisterViewModel as a parameter but then trying to instantiate m as UserCreateViewModel() But I am not sure how to get my registerViewModel into the view via UserCreateViewModel.

View:

`````
@model ComtrexCloudReporting.Models.UserCreateNewViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserCreate";
}




<div class="spacerBody">
    <h2 class="admin-home-link orange-titles orange-titles-large">@Html.ActionLink("Create Users", "AdminIndex")</h2>

    <div class="to-link navlinks"> @Html.ActionLink("Users", "UserList") | @Html.ActionLink("Manage User Role", "RoleManageUser")</div>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration Form</legend>
            <ol class="comtrexBlue-text">
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                </li>

                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                </li>
            </ol>
            <button class="btn larger" type="submit">Create</button>
        </fieldset>

    }````
`````

Comment: In your view page, use `@model RegisterViewModel` statement.

Comment: Hey thanks but I also need to be able to access what is in the UserCreateViewModel and I have gotten error messages when I try to use both statements saying I can only access one per view model

Comment: Show ur View's code.

Comment: Ok I am going to edit in the Post

Comment: Oh maybe its the Models. statement? Maybe it should be ViewModels

Comment: No nevermind I checked and this ViewModel is in the Model statement

Comment: Your code looks OK. You shouldn't have error like "..one view model per page..."

Comment: I tried using both and it says only one Model statement is allowed. am I not doing this correctly: ````model ComtrexCloudReporting.Models.UserCreateNewViewModel
@model ComtrexCloudReporting.Models.RegisterViewModel````

Comment: You should use only one, forget ur UserCreateNewViewModel, only use ur RegisterViewModel.

Comment: But the problem is that I need to have other stuff later on for additional functionality in the UserCreateNewViewModel thanks again for all your help

Comment: what you can do is make your UserCreateNewViewModel inherit from RegisterViewModel and use UserCreateNewViewModel as strongly typed Model in your view.

Comment: I understand what you would like to achieve, u need to use inheritance to solve this if you cant touch the original viewmodel.

Comment: Oh great how can I have it inherit from it. Right now I just have: ````  public class UserCreateNewViewModel
  {     public RegisterViewModel Register = new RegisterViewModel();   } ````

Comment: its so simple just use colon(:) to inharit fromRegisterViewModel Like UserCreateNewVieModel : RegisterViewModel{   additional properties here }

Comment: @MuhammadAli im sorry I'm not super familar you are saying to do this : ````  public class UserCreateNewViewModel : RegisterViewModel 
  {   }```` Correct?

Comment: @MuhammadAli thank you so much that worked!!!! :)

Comment: If you don't mind could you explain a little bit about why this model needs to be inherited like that in the passed I have been able to pass many models just by instantiating or "newing it up" as i have heard it being used. Thank you for your help @MuhammadAli

Comment: What inheritence is  "is a" relationship which mean when you inherit UserCreateNewViewModel from RegisterViewModel it 
is actually now a RegisterViewModel but when you new things up like public RegisterViewModel Register = new RegisterViewModel();
it is called "has a" relationship or composition it means Now your UserCreateNewViewModel contains an instance of RegisterViewModel but is 
not actually a RegisterViewModel.

Comment: so when you pass UserCreateNewViewModel from your view MVC Model Binder will bind to UserCreateNewViewModel and if 
you use RegisterViewModel in your view it will bind to RegisterviewModel.

Comment: @MuhammadAli  great explanations! Thank you

Comment: you are very welcome :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195144/discussion-between-megan-meluskey-and-muhammad-ali).

Comment: Hey would you happen to know the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653914/how-to-pass-data-from-a-view-to-the-controller-using-the-webmatrix-websecurity-d